# Dojo mixin two Arrays how to?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dojo

I have following situation:

I have an variable array like this:

```
[
    {
        id: "foo",
        value: "bar"
    },
    {
        id: "baz",
        value: "buz"
    }
]
```

And I have a defaults array like this:

```
[
    {
        id: "foo",
        value: "default"
    },
    {
        id: "bar",
        value: "default"
    },
    {
        id: "baz",
        value: "default"
    }
]
```

I would like to compare those two arrays and mix them together by adding the missing defaults to the first array.

This is what I want as output:

```
[
    {
        id: "foo",
        value: "bar"  // keep unchanged because it was already there
    },
    {
        id: "bar",
        value: "default"   // use the default because it was not in there
    },
    {
        id: "baz",
        value: "buz"   // also keep because it was already in the first array
    }
]
```

What is the nicest way to achieve this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways how to solve it would be filtering the second array from the entries with the same `id` as in the first array and joining it into one array of objects.

```js
var arr1=[{id:"foo",value:"bar"},{id:"baz",value:"buz"}],
    arr2=[{id:"foo",value:"default"},{id:"bar",value:"default"},{id:"baz",value:"default"}];

    var arr3 = arr2.filter(v => arr1.every(c => c.id != v.id));
    console.log([...arr1, ...arr3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, It is directly not possible by using dojo - lang.mixin.. because mixin basically deals with json object istead of array of objects (in your case).

**Solution -** I just wrote a  JavaScript function which will return you the merged array.

```js
var baseArray = [{
            id: "foo",
            value: "bar"
        },
        {
            id: "baz",
            value: "buz"
        },
        {
            key: "key",
            value: "value"
        }
    ];

    var defaultArray = [{
            id: "foo",
            value: "default"
        },
        {
            id: "bar",
            value: "default"
        },
        {
            id: "baz",
            value: "default"
        }
    ];

var result = _mixinArrays(baseArray , defaultArray );
console.log(result);

function _mixinArrays(a, b){
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        var matched = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (b[i].id == a[j].id) {               
                matched = true;
            }
        }
        if (!matched) {
            a.push(b[i]);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Hoping this will help you :)

Comment: This solution does not take elements into consideration that have no ID, they should be added as well since they have no matching pair

Comment: I added one more object in base array which desn't have id..I updated the code accordingly so  it will consider that too... {
            key: "key",
            value: "value"
        }...